# Active Directory Linked to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, active-directory

I have a current project designed in Vb.net 2008 that fetch users stored in Active Directory. Is there any way to query those lists of users from SQL server then Populate it into Datagridview in vb.net?

Comment: why dont use LDAP query in your vb.net project and get the list from Active Directorio (AD)? SQLServer relationship with the list of AD you need?

Comment: Yes ***it can be done***, create a linked server, obtain LDAP info (used for your query), then use OpenQuery to do your selects... This question is also very broad and really can't be answered in one sitting. Although the information I provided is the steps you need to take in order for hitting against AD. Then create a procedure you can call from code side to fill a DataTable and thenot set the DataSource of the DataGridView.

Comment: I am planning to fetch specific user from Active directory through the use of SQL Server. Then the next step if a have those data, I need to populate it on a datagridview in vb.net. Is this too complicated?

Answer (score 1):

You can use query Active Directory directly using the OPENQUERY command like in this article:

> [Querying Active Directory from SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2580/querying-active-directory-data-from-sql-server/)

```sql
SELECT * FROM OpenQuery ( 
  ADSI,  
  'SELECT displayName, telephoneNumber, mail, mobile, facsimileTelephoneNumber 
  FROM  ''LDAP://DOMAIN.com/OU=Players,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com'' 
  WHERE objectClass =  ''User'' 
  ') AS tblADSI
ORDORDER BY displayname
```

Comment: Since when did we start providing Google search services, there's nothing in your answer that is any different than the article link you posted. It's clear in the comments what the OP needs to do. How does your answer benefit the OP?

Comment: I was merely linking to an article that describes the process as I did not want to post the actual code we use.